# How to send custom emails to SNS topic subscriptions using AWS SDK

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, amazon-sns, amazon-ses

I have a requirement to send the email containing some business related text to all the subscribers of a SNS topic using AWS SDK for .Net. How can I do that?

Comment: Could you please edit your question to provide more information? For example, what do you mean by "send the email"? Are the subscribers all subscribed via the Email protocol? Are you simply asking how to send a message to an Amazon SNS topic? Or do you wish to send a message via Amazon SES? If you can provide more information, we can provide a better answer.

Comment: maybe, check the tutorial: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sns-tutorial-publish-message-to-topic.html#publish-message-to-topic-aws-dot-net